# understand the condition that allows the existence of the solution of an inhomogeneous system

Tags: linear-algebra

(I am trying to understand a theorem from my textbook)

---

**[Theorem]:** Consider the inhomogeneous system with the rank of $k,\ (k<n)$:
$$\begin{matrix}a_{11}x_1+a_{12}x_2+...+a_{1n}x_n=b_1\\a_{21}x_1+a_{22}x_2+...+a_{2n}x_n=b_2\\......\\a_{n1}x_1+a_{n2}x_2+...+a_{nn}x_n=b_n\end{matrix}$$
The homogeneous adjoint of this system is then:
$$\begin{matrix}\bar{a}_{11}y_1+\bar{a}_{21}y_2+...+\bar{a}_{n1}y_n=0\\\bar{a}_{12}y_1+\bar{a}_{22}y_2+...+\bar{a}_{n2}y_n=0\\......\\\bar{a}_{1n}y_1+\bar{a}_{2n}y_2+...+\bar{a}_{nn}y_n=0\end{matrix}$$
We conclude that:
 *A necessary and sufficient condition for the inhomogeneous system to have a solution is that the vector $B=(b_1,b_2,...,b_n)$ be orthogonal to all the vectors obtained as solutions of the homogeneous adjoint system.*

---

**[Question]:**
I have read the derivation of this theorem and understand all the calculations to obtain it, but I can't understand it intuitively. Why is the orthogonality here determines the existence of the solution? Is there any narrative or geometry based explanation for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the solutions of $Ax=b$,
first we denote $A$ as a set of column vectors $(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\cdots,\alpha_n)$,
so a necessary and sufficient condition for the inhomogeneous system to have a solution is that $\exists x$, s.t.

$x_1\alpha_1+x_2\alpha_2+\cdots+x_n\alpha_n=b$, which means that $b\in L(\alpha_i)$.

Also we know that $V=U\oplus U^{\perp}$, so $b\in L(\alpha_i)\Longleftrightarrow b \perp v,\forall v \in L(a_i)^{\perp}$.

Actually you can find a set of orthogonal basis of {$\alpha_i$},  so  to have the solution of  inhomogeneous system $Ax=0$

we can expand {$\alpha_i$} into the basis of $V$, and we can get the basis of the solution.

Plus we have $\ker \phi^{*}=($ $\mathrm{Im}$ $\phi$)$^{\perp}$.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, so in my case I understand that all solutions of the homogeneous adjoint system with rank of $k$ belongs to a subspace with dimension of $n-k$. But is that the only thing that guarantees the existence of the solution? And is it unnecessary for the theorem from my textbook to emphasis the condition relies on the solution of the adjoint system, because any system that generates $n-k$ dimension solutions can satisfy the orthogonality?

Comment: Yes,you are right. Having a solution can be well converted into the rank of augmented matrix. But the theorem in your textbook is absolutely right though. Weird there but correct.

Comment: Now that I think about it, I guess it's just because it is convenient to use the adjoint to construct the needed system ......